# How to update parent page from popover controller

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, popover, angular8

I have a popoverController and want to update a variable on the parent page, that is visible in the background (bottom, because the popover is not fullscreen). Is there an easy way to do this?

Because `this.parentPage.setXY('xy')` doesn't work.
No provider for ParentPage and I don't want to add it just for one use.

Are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use output in Angular framework.

something like this:

```
export class ChildComponent {
@Output() yearUpdated = new EventEmitter<number>();
year : 2019;

setCurrentYear() {
    this.yearUpdated.emit(this.year);
}

}

//Then the value yearUpdated will be available in your parent component.

//In your parent template:

<app-parent>
<app-child (yearUpdated)="onYearUpdate($event)"></app-child>
</app-parent>

//In your typescript file:

export class ParentComponent {
currentYear : number

onYearUpdate(year: number) {
    this.currentYear = year;
}

}
```

Comment: And you can also use Angular services, thats another option.